# How to create an array from csv string?

Tags: php, arrays, select, csv

Im trying to create and array from a csv variable:

```
$csv="one,two,tree,four";


$bits = split(',',$csv);
$elements = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($bits);$i++) 
{
    $item .= '"'.$bits[$i].'"=>"'.$bits[$i].'",';
}

$item = substr($item, 0, -1);
$ara=array($item);

$USE['list'] = $ara;
```

I need to obtain something like this, and thats all:

```
$USE['list'] = array("one"=>"one","two"=>"two","tree"=>"tree","four"=>"four");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user113215 's answer is good. However, if you really need an associative array :

```
$csv = 'one,two,tree,four';
$USE['list'] = array();

$bits = explode(',', $csv);

foreach($bits as $bit) 
{
    $USE['list'][$bit] = $bit;
}
```

Please note that the **split** function is deprecated, use **explode** instead.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a basic solution in your code. The only line you need is this:

```
$bits = split(',', $csv);
```

With your sample input, this will give you the following array:

```
$bits = array("one", "two", "three", "four");
```

If you really need `$USE['list']` in key-value pair style (I'm not sure how this is helpful, since the key and the value will be the same), you could do something like this:

```
$USE['list'] = array();
foreach($bits as $bit) {
    $USE['list'][$bit] = $bit;
}
```

However, as others have mentioned, this is definitely not the safest way to parse CSV data (it won't properly deal with values that contain commas, values that have been quoted, etc.). If you can't use `str_getcsv()` because you don't have PHP 5.3.0 or higher, check out [parsecsv-for-php](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/).

Comment: yes I know.. but I need to create the other array for the app foreach:           $USE['list'] = array("one"=>"one","two"=>"two","tree"=>"tree","four"=>"four");        if(count($USE['list'])>0) {
 foreach($USE['list'] as $i=>$v) {
  if($k==0) {
   $username = $i;
  }
  $k++;
 }
}

Comment: Can you make another edit to your answer? I didn't see your first edit when I cast my down-vote, so now it's locked in unless you edit it again.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté No worries. You were correct to downvote all our answers. `str_getcsv()` is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of naive implementations here that should not be used in any but the most basic cases.

The proper way to parse CSV in PHP is to use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

Or, at the very least, any self-rolled solution should account for quoted values (at which point you also need to consider escaped quotes). Otherwise, you'll get incorrect conversions and potentially corrupt the CSV data (creating a nightmare for the next guy who has to use the corrupted CSV data).

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use split as it has been depreciated.

```
<?php

$csv="one,two,tree,four";


$bits = explode(',',$csv);
foreach($bits as $value) {
    $array[$value] = $value;
}

   $USE['list'] = $array;

var_dump($USE['list']);

?>
```